# AFNetworking 2.0 Request w. Custom Header

Tags: ios, header, http-headers, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Ive tried to avoid asking such a newb question on here, but im a Android dev learning IOS and I cant figure out for the life of me how to add a simple header to my post requests using AFNetworking 2.0. Below is my code so far which works if i want to make a request that doesnt require a header.Could anyone show me via adding to my snippet or providing a alternate one that does this? I came across this tut: http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445  that shows how to add a header under the "A RESTful Class" heading , but its for afnetworking 1.0 and is now depreciated as far as i can tell.

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"uid": @"1"};
    AFHT
    [manager POST:@"http://myface.com/api/profile/format/json" parameters:parameters  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

        self.feedArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"feed"];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } ];
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Under `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` you will notice a property called `requestSerializer`. This is of type `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`, and requests made through the HTTP manager are constructed with the headers specified by this object.

So, try this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"SomeValue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SomeHeaderField"]

//Make your requests
```

You can read the headers dictionary from the request serializer as follows:

```
manager.requestSerializer.HTTPRequestHeaders
```

Note that once you set a header this way, it will be used for all other operations!

Answer (score 0):

```
 [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"staging" password:@"dustylendpa"];
```

Comment: Your answer should contains an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Comment: Class method reference: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html#//api/name/setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:password: